# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@70d656a7 testClass

Tags: junit, mockito

Junit Test cases running locally but while deploying in DEV environment getting error "IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext"
below i have added ful log details where you can find the exact error.
please help me to fix this issue. Thank You
**Error Log**

```
ngframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fec3550d], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[ERROR]   CommonUtilsTest.validateSN_Max_Test » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@744ab62 testClass = com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util.CommonUtilsTest, locations = [], classes = [com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.ApplicationTest], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@13b3d178, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51c693d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4b5189ac, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@1acaf3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7c51f34b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fec3550d], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[ERROR]   CommonUtilsTest.validateSN_Min_Test » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@744ab62 testClass = com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util.CommonUtilsTest, locations = [], classes = [com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.ApplicationTest], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@13b3d178, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51c693d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4b5189ac, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@1acaf3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7c51f34b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fec3550d], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[ERROR]   CommonUtilsTest.validateSN_Test » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@744ab62 testClass = com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util.CommonUtilsTest, locations = [], classes = [com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.ApplicationTest], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@13b3d178, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51c693d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4b5189ac, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@1acaf3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7c51f34b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fec3550d], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[ERROR]   CoreUtilTest.convertStringToInt_Test » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@2339b8f6 testClass = com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util.CoreUtilTest, locations = [], classes = [com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@13b3d178, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51c693d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4b5189ac, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@1acaf3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7c51f34b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fec3550d], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[ERROR]   CoreUtilTest.getTimeoutInt_Test » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@2339b8f6 testClass = com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util.CoreUtilTest, locations = [], classes = [com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@13b3d178, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51c693d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4b5189ac, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@1acaf3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7c51f34b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fec3550d], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[ERROR]   CoreUtilTest.trimString_Test » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@2339b8f6 testClass = com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util.CoreUtilTest, locations = [], classes = [com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@13b3d178, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51c693d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4b5189ac, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@1acaf3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7c51f34b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fec3550d], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 46, Failures: 0, Errors: 46, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:31 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-03T16:32:57Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) on project os-api-asyncdelegator: 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/jenkins/workspace/ON_os-api-asyncdelegator_develop/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**applicationTest.java**

```
package com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestClassOrder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator", "com.hp.os.common" })
@TestClassOrder(ClassOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class ApplicationTest {

    public void contextLoads() {
        String test = "TestingAssert";
        assertNotNull(test);
    }
}
```

**Application.Java**

```
package com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;

import com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.config.SolaceFactory;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPException;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeIn;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme;



@EnableWebFlux
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Asyncdelegator API", version = "1.0", description = "Asyncdelegator Information"))
@SecurityScheme(name = "asyncdelegatorapi", scheme = "bearer", type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator", "com.hp.os.common" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    SolaceFactory sf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        try {
            sf.initialize();
        } catch (JCSMPException je) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            je.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        }
    }

}
```

**CoreUtil.Java**

```
package com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public final class CoreUtil
{
    
    private static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 2000;
    
    /**
     * Private Constructor
     */
    private CoreUtil()
    {
        
    }


    /**
     * Value Of
     * Instantiates a generic class based on the string
     * Currently, expects all string values to be JSON
     * Note: Removed the URLDecoder since incoming values are not URL encoded
     * @param <T> Generic Class
     * @param clazz Class of <T>
     * @param value String Serialization of <T>
     * @return Instance of <T>
     */
    public static <T> T valueOf( final Class<T> clazz, final String value )
    {
        if ( clazz.isInstance( Collections.EMPTY_LIST ) || clazz.isInstance( Collections.EMPTY_MAP )
                || clazz.isInstance( Collections.EMPTY_SET ) ) {
            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(); 
            Type type = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
            JavaType jt = om.getTypeFactory().constructType( type );
            return CoreUtil.<T>valueOfJSON( jt, value );
        }

        // Otherwise return the non-container valueOfJSON()
        return valueOfJSON( clazz, value );
    }

    /**
     * Value Of
     * Instantiates a generic class based on the string
     * Currently, expects all string values to be JSON
     * Note: Removed the URLDecoder since incoming values are not URL encoded
     * @param <T> Class Type
     * @param typeRef JavaType of "container"
     * @param value String Serialization of <T>
     * @return Instance of <T>
     */
    public static <T> T valueOf( final JavaType typeRef, final String value )
    {
        return CoreUtil.<T>valueOfJSON( typeRef, value );
    }

    /**
     * Value Of JSON for Containers- Deserializes an Object from JSON
     * @param <T> Generic Type
     * @param typeRef Type Reference of "container"
     * @param json JSON String
     * @return Instance of Class
     */
    private static <T> T valueOfJSON( final JavaType typeRef, final String json )
    {
        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader( json );

        try {
            return m.readValue( sr, typeRef );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Value Of JSON - Deserializes an Object from JSON
     * @param <T> Generic Type
     * @param clazz Class
     * @param json JSON String
     * @return Instance of Class
     */
    public static <T> T valueOfJSON( final Class<T> clazz, final String json )
    {
        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader( json );

        try {
            return m.readValue( sr, clazz );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            log.error(e.getMessage()); 
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * To JSON String - Serializes an Object to JSON
     * @param obj Object
     * @return JSON String
     */
    public static String toStringJSON( final Object obj )
    {
        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        try {
            m.writeValue( sw, obj );
            return sw.toString();
        } catch ( IOException e  ) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        } 

        return null;
    }
    
    public static String trimString( final String str) {
        Optional<String> op = Optional.ofNullable(str);
        if(op.isPresent())
            return str.trim();
        else
            return "";
        
    }
    public static int convertStringToInt(String str) {
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            log.error("NumberFormatException:  "+ e.getMessage());
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    public static int getTimeoutInt(String timeoutStr) {
        int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        try {
            timeout = Integer.valueOf(timeoutStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        }
        return timeout;
    }
}
```

**CoreUtilTest.java**

```
package com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestClassOrder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.ApplicationTest;
import com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.model.AsyncObligationRequests;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestClassOrder(ClassOrderer.ClassName.class)
@SpringBootTest()
//@SpringBootTest()
public class CoreUtilTest {
    @Test
    void trimString_Test() {
        String str = CoreUtil.trimString("Test");
        assertThat(str).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void convertStringToInt_Test() {
        int i = CoreUtil.convertStringToInt("10");
        assertThat(i).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void getTimeoutInt_Test() {
        int i = CoreUtil.getTimeoutInt("Test");
        assertThat(i).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

**CommonUtilsTest.Java**

```
package com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.util;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestClassOrder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;

import com.hp.it.os.asyncdelegator.ApplicationTest;
import com.hp.os.common.logger.Message;
import com.hp.os.common.util.Constants;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestClassOrder(ClassOrderer.ClassName.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTest.class)
//@SpringBootTest()
public class CommonUtilsTest {

    @Autowired
    CommonUtils commonUtils;
    @Mock
    CommonUtils commonUtil;

    @Mock
    ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint;
    private static final String SLASH = "#";
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    private String defaultLocaleLanguage;
    private String defaultLocaleCountry;
    private int size;
    private Locale defaultLocale = null;
    private static final String UNDER_SCORE = "_";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.ISO_DATE_FORMAT);
    String todayAsString = df.format(new Date());
    private final List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()));

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        defaultLocaleCountry = "US";
    }

    @Test
    void isValidISOCountry_Test() {
        boolean b = commonUtils.isValidISOCountry(defaultLocaleCountry);
        assertThat(b).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void getUserLocale_Test() {
        String str = commonUtils.getUserLocale(defaultLocaleCountry);
        assertThat(str).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void getCountryUserLocale_Test() {
        String str = commonUtils.getCountryUserLocale(defaultLocaleCountry);
        assertThat(str).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void getLanguageUserLocale_Test() {
        String str = commonUtils.getLanguageUserLocale(defaultLocaleCountry);
        assertThat(str).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void isValidDateFormat_Test() {
        boolean b = commonUtils.isValidDateFormat("11/02/2023", "MM/dd/yy");
        assertThat(b).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void getLocalizedPn_Test() {
        String str = commonUtil.getLocalizedPn("BRBFD3V125");
        assertThat(str).isNull();
    }

    @Test
    void validateSN_Max_Test() {
        boolean b = commonUtils.validateSN("BRBFD3V12500000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        assertEquals(b, false);
    }

    @Test
    void validateSN_Min_Test() {
        boolean b = commonUtils.validateSN("BRB");
        assertEquals(b, false);
    }

    @Test
    void validateSN_Test() {
        boolean b = commonUtils.validateSN("BRBFD3V125");
        assertEquals(b, true);
    }

    @Test
    void validatePN_Test() {
        boolean b = commonUtils.validatePN("T3U56A");
        assertEquals(b, true);
    }

    @Test
    void validatePN_False_Test() {
        boolean b = commonUtils.validatePN("T3");
        assertEquals(b, false);
    }

    @Test
    void convertDateToString_Test() {
        Date d1 = new Date();
        String str = commonUtils.convertDateToString(d1, "dd-MM-yyyy");
        assertThat(str).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void convertStringToLocalDate_Test() {
        Date date = new Date();
        // Instantiating the SimpleDateFormat class
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        // Formatting the obtained date
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
        LocalDate str = commonUtils.convertStringToLocalDate(formattedDate, "dd-MM-yyyy");
        assertThat(str).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void appendStatusCode_Test() {
        String str = commonUtils.appendStatusCode(defaultLocaleCountry, "test", "test");
        assertThat(str).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void isValidAlphaNumericValue_Test() {
        boolean b = commonUtils.isValidAlphaNumericValue("test");
        assertEquals(b, true);
    }

    @Test
    void validateAlloedPNList_Test() {
        List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
        str.add("Test1");
        str.add("Test3");
        str.add("Test4");
        boolean b = commonUtils.validateAlloedPNList(str, RequestUtils.getObligationRequest().getValue1()
                .getLnkServiceObligationProductObjectOfServiceIdentifier().getHpProductNumber());
        assertEquals(b, false);
    }

    @Test
    void buildMessage_Test() {
        Message msg = commonUtils.buildMessage("apigeeCorrelationID", SLASH, SLASH, SLASH, SLASH, size, SLASH, SLASH,
                size, SLASH, todayAsString, defaultLocaleCountry, defaultLocaleLanguage, defaultLocaleCountry,
                UNDER_SCORE, SLASH);
        assertThat(msg).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Comment: junit4 or junit5 remove unrelated tags

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: please help to fix this issue

Comment: added complete stack stackstrce

Comment: Can you run the test in your IDE and look at the result . You should get more useful information

Comment: It is working in local IDE, issue comes when deploying in DEV server

Comment: run mvn with `-X` to get more information

Comment: Ran in local IDE Build success

Comment: C:\Users\DASCEIS\.m2\repository\com\hp\it\psoit\os-api-asyncdelegator\maven
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-04T18:28:15+05:30

Comment: need help on the above issue, any help will be appreciated. Thank you